# Can UNNotificationContentExtension handle swipe?

Tags: ios, swift

I have been working  with UNNotificationContentExtension and I have created a custom UI containing a scrollView. I load the scrollView with Image View and it's an Image Carousel and the image carousel should move horizontally.

My scroll view is getting set properly however the scrollView does not scroll horizontally.

I checked that my images are in the carousel by programmatically scrolling with

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: y), animated: true)
```

Also, each of my images should open different pages in my app. So what I have done is added tap gesture to the individual imageViews.

So my questions are,

**Is it possible for UNNotificationContentExtension to translate a scrollView in horizontal direction?**

**Is it possible to open different pages in app based on the images clicked?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my questions are,
>
> Is it possible for UNNotificationContentExtension to translate a scrollView in horizontal direction?
>
> Is it possible to open different pages in app based on the images clicked?

No and no. UNNotificationContentExtension is not user interactive in any way, except for elements like the Play button that the runtime inserts for you upon request.

**EDIT**: Note that this was correct in iOS 11 and before, but changed in iOS 12, where it became possible, in the NSExtensionAttributes in the *Info.plist*, to add the `UNNotificationExtensionUserInteractionEnabled` Boolean key and set its value to `YES`. Now the entire mechanism for user interaction springs to life.

Comment: "Play button that the runtime inserts for you upon request" . Can you explain this more or can you provide a link. I didn't understand. @matt

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension/1829403-mediaplaypausebuttontype

Comment: But iMessage has scroll in content extention

Comment: you can view previous message in content extension using scroll

Comment: @Koushik it is possible to allow vertical scrolling by setting the height of the view to something larger than the screen, which I think is what iMessage does.

Comment: You can set preferred height and it might start scrolling

Answer (score 0):

> So my questions are,
>
> Is it possible for UNNotificationContentExtension to translate a scrollView in horizontal direction?
>
> Is it possible to open different pages in app based on the images clicked?

Yes and yes. Set UNNotificationExtensionUserInteractionEnabled in your plist file to YES. The previous answer said "No," but this is no longer correct as of iOS 12.

When asked, this was not possible, and was not for iOS 10 and iOS 11.

Comment: All you had to do was comment on my answer and I'd have changed it (as I've now done). Vandalizing my answer was an unnecessarily rude way to get my attention.

Comment: Did not mean to vandalize. Just edit and put in the correct one :) @matt